# Can "I" grow american beautyberry?

Tags: hardiness-zone

I just heard about the american beautyberry, and was wondering What zones can I grow it in?

It sounds very intriguing, and would love to try having different foods for me to eat.

Comment: It might be easier to answer this if you explain what kind of climate you live in, or what region. Unless you have several gardens in several different climates?

Comment: Zone 4A in MN trying to do a major food diversification.

Comment: OK. Maybe you could add that to OP. I don't know the answer myself, I just thought you'd have an easier time getting answers if you add that. And maybe change the title to "Can I grow American Beautyberry in Minesota" or something like that.

Comment: Some of the questions I ask are for general purposes, not just for me similar to how other sites have general questions.

Comment: Oh I see. I misunderstood, because the title indicates that it's just for you.

Comment: Maybe a better title would be "Where can American Beautyberry be grown?"

Comment: That is why editing is on this site.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you suggesting I edit your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

American beautyberry is actually Callicarpa Americana; it's an ornamental plant rather than an edible one. The berries have been used to treat colic, in the form of tea, so I guess, if you suffer from colic, you might find it useful. Deciduous shrub, usually around six to nine feet tall, depending on conditions and whether it's pruned regularly, bright purple berries held in drupes which often persist for some months, though cattle may forage some. However, you'd need a greenhouse with heat in winter in your USDA zone; it grows in zones 7 to 11.

Comment: the question wasn't specific for me, but specific to everyone.

Comment: @blackthumb The way your question is articulated makes it sound like you are asking if **you** can grow the berry, rather than what in which zones the berry will grow.

Comment: Someone in a different zone may want to know if they can also, so that's how I look at the questions.

Comment: @blackthumb Yeah, I understand :)